# How do I do a diagonal grid layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to develop a diagonal grid layout for a project gallery. I've found a project that have something like I need - http://neolab.no/.

Here's the layout that I have to do.
http://felipefernandes.nu/beta/fsmohan/screenshot/Wireframe_Site_FSMohan-05.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: I can see two approaches, lots of images, or css3 rotate. The first will be more compatible.

Comment: Today you can accomplish this with css grids and a transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options, but none are terribly good:

- Chop up images: this will look fine, but your hovers will be difficult since they will be based on rectangles.
- Use an image map: your hover areas will be able to line up correctly, but effects will be difficult.
- CSS3 transform: if you can deal with IE9+ only, this may be an option.  You'd have to save your images rotated clockwise, then rotate them back counterclockwise via CSS (or vice versa).  Here's [a quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tbucy/).
- Use `<canvas>`
- Use Flash: this may honestly be your best bet for functionality and looks, but forcing your website to depend on a plugin has a world of issues.

Comment: Thanks Travis! I did using CSS3 Tranform and absoluting position for each block. The con of this solution is if I'd need an responsive project I'll have to position all over again one by one. But OK. The link is here [link](http://felipefernandes.nu/beta/fsmohan/)

Comment: @RipCorP, Wow, that turned out really well!  Good job!